# XSD file help required for validating an XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation, xsd-validation

I am having problem in writing a xsd file for validating an specific XML format. The XML format goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:customers xmlns:p="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com NewXMLSchema.xsd ">
<p:customer>
   <p:name salutation="Mr."/>
   <p:age>25</p:age>
   <p:discount>6</p:discount>
</p:customer>
<p:customer>
   <p:name salutation="Ms."/>
   <p:age>35</p:age>
   <p:discount>10</p:discount>
</p:customer>
........
........
</p:customers>
```

The number of customer will vary; it may be one or more.

This is the XSD i came up with for validating this XML:

```
<xs:complexType name="customerName">
    <xs:attribute name="salutation" type="xs:string" default="Mr."></xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="customerAge">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="18"></xs:minInclusive>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="60"></xs:maxInclusive>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="customerdiscount">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="5"></xs:minInclusive>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="30"></xs:maxInclusive>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="customer">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="customerName"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="age" type="customerAge"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="discount" type="customerdiscount"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="customers">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="customer" type="customer"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="customer" type="customer"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="customer" type="customer"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In the above XSD, i am facing a few problems, need the resolutions:

1) I want the name to be something like this:

```
<name salutation="Mr.">XYZ NAme</name>
```

2) The customer names may be one or more. In the above code, i used sequence and hence there can be 3 and only 3 customer. This thing I need to rectify.

Please help me with these two stuff in XSD.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

1) You can extend xs:string as a complex type with an attribute:

```
 <xs:element name="name">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:simpleContent>
       <xs:extension base="xs:string">
         <xs:attribute name="salutation" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

2) You can use minOccurs and maxOccurs:

```
<xs:element name="customer" type="customer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

Also, I think you need to specify the schema's target namespace at the top:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns:p="http://www.w3schools.com">
```

and prefix type references with p (because all types defined by the schema are in the target namespace):

```
 <xs:element name="age" type="p:customerAge"/>
 <xs:element name="discount" type="p:customerdiscount"/>
 <xs:element name="customer" type="p:customer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

With these changes, I could successfully validate the document above (with the dots removed).